# Main Line into House 1" OD Copper, what fitting

Tags: plumbing, hvac, water

The main line coming into my house is 7/8 inch copper, .99 OD. I can't find any 7/8 fittings other than a reducer to 3/4. Seems like a 1 inch fitting would be to big, whats on there now is tight fitting as you'd expect from any matching size pipe/fitting. The main shutoff valve needs to be replaced and I don't want to torque it as much as it would take to remove the current one. Currently it has a 7/8 to 1.25 FIP, 1.25 to 1 hex nipple, 1 inch regular port valve. Pretty sure the valve is the original 40 yr old.

Edit: Title updated

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Does someone know where to get 7/8 inch fittings? Or does a 1" fitting work and if so is it common practices now days?

Comment: What type of copper tubing and pipe are measured differently pipe is measured on ID. tubing is measured on OD and yes I have seen tubing used as a supply.

Comment: @EdBeal Sorry not sure if there was a question in there. I suppose to be totally accurate it would probably be classed as 1" tubing. The main supply is was a roll of 1" OD copper to the curb stop. The only fittings I can find (home depot, ect.) are for 1" ID copper pipe (think that's worded right).

Comment: Wow, that's a flare fitting on the incoming copper. I bet it **is** 1" tubing...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Don't suppose you know where a guy could get his hands on a new one of those?

Comment: A good plumbing shop (not a big-box hardware store) will have flare fittings, The problem is the size, 1" tubing and flare fittings for it are... rare. Kinda like the buggy whip, no demand. I would save and reuse what you have on that old line, but convert to modern size/fittings for everything downstream.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Everything downstream is already modern standard, mostly copper, the PEX pictured only goes to the meter. Part of what started this is needing a new water softener and house filter, I'm going to have the cold switched to PEX until right before it branches going into the foundation. In person, the first brass piece looks sweated on, not certain. The 2 other options I came up to start fresh: 1) with grab a 7/8 to 3/4 adapter, with a full port valve would probably be better than whats on there. 2) try a 1" FTG to 1 or 3/4 C.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Thanks for you help. Going to give one of these a shot. If it fits it is exactly what I was looking for yesterday. [link](https://www.menards.com/main/plumbing/pipe-fittings/copper-pipe-tubing-fittings/nibco-reg-ftg-x-fip-lead-free-copper-adapter/9028750/p-1444449071538.htm)

Comment: Instead of worrying about the shutoff valve, I suggest you do something about that earthing point.

Comment: @SolarMike You don't think my clamp would hold up ;). I do need to do something with it while copper is still booming. House runs to ground right at the box, that a remnant.

Comment: the linked "1" FTG" adapter has an O.D. of 1.125" and is designed to insert **into** a 1" sweat fitting (like a 1" copper *pipe* would); 1" copper pipe is 1.125 O.D.), I don't see how that is going to help you with *tubing* that is 1" O.D. Again, *there is no such thing as 7/8" copper pipe*.

Comment: If it were me I would special order a compression fitting for 1" O.D. tube that coverts directly to standard pipe thread, like this one at McmasterCarr: https://www.mcmaster.com/5220K85/

Answer (score 0):

In the US, copper "refrigeration" tubing is measured by the O.D. whereas copper *pipe* sizes are *nominal* (in other words sized by nomenclature where nothing actually *measures* to the named size). There is no 7/8" *pipe*, but there is 1" OD tubing.

It would be very odd to have a copper *tubing* main line, but odder things have happened. I suspect that, if indeed you are working with tubing, it is a repair that someone cobbled together at that section (rather than the entire main being tubing) because they had some 1" OD tubing on-hand.

It is unclear exactly what your question is, but somebody already converted your tube to FIP (at least on one side) so you should use that; on the other side get a 1" compression fitting to convert to pipe thread as well.

Comment: I'll see what the plumber says I guess. Wanted to have a fitting on hand and just replace it, like I said I don't want to torque the line as that would be the end. I couldn't wouldn't afford to repair it. It's impossible for the current stuff to be a repair job. Slab on grade and I gutted the whole house 2 years ago. Foundation hasn't been touched.

Comment: To emphasize: There is copper pipe and there is copper tubing , they are different sizes although they may look similar.